# Generate Lat-Long pair matrix in python with a certain interval in a certain range

Tags: python

I would like to generate in Python a Matrix, which should look like the following:

```
    Lat       Long
0   40.400    9.975
1   40.401    9.975
2   40.402    9.975
3   40.403    9.975

.... 
N   40.425    9.995
```

The values should reach from 40.400 to 40.425 (Lat) and from 9.975 to 9.995 (Long) and the matrix should include all combinations of lat-long pairs.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is there a problem with just using two `for` loops to achieve this? Or a nested list comprehension?

Comment: Another homework assignment on SO?